# Arduino motor shield

Tags: hardware, arduino-motor-shield

I'm making a soccer car with arduino. And I have this undocumented motor control shield. So I don't know how to program it. I've tried to code it as if it be an H bridge, but is not working. Someone know which are the pins that I have to use? 
The plate is from DK Electronics, and says motor control shield for arduino.

Don't know why but the image can't be upload from my phone.

As I can't show more this way I have published on my Twitter account the image, if you can I'll be grateful.
Link: https://twitter.com/ricardovaras_99/status/789249497322889216

This is the code I used guided by some internet articles about the Arduino's original motors control shield.

```
 pinMode(8,OUTPUT);       //Channel A Brake Pin Initialize
 pinMode(9,OUTPUT);       //Channel B Brake Pin Initialize 
 pinMode(12,OUTPUT);      //Channel A Direction Pin Initialize
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);      //Channel B Direction Pin Initialize
```

Comment: No one will be able to assist you until we have more information. The photo may help, but more importantly is the documentation which begs the question:why did you buy a product with no documentation?

Comment: would it be this in any case?? http://www.oddwires.com/motor-shield-for-arduino/

Comment: You are going to have to try harder. A shield which you don't have a photo of, combined with code you haven't posted, and you are asking for help?

Comment: @canadiancyborg yes is exactly that one

Comment: @NickGammon Done, please, help me :'D

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum Done, the code is there, and an image I've posted on twitter because my phone, or my internet are sad or something.

Comment: That link doesn't lead me to an image. Get to a PC or something and get the image into this post. I have long since cancelled my Twitter account because they were driving me mad with spam. Even afterwards, so I had to make an automatic email rule to send all their stuff directly to the spam folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the fact that you agree it looks like [this](http://www.oddwires.com/motor-shield-for-arduino/), a search reveals it is a knock-off of the [Adafruit V1 motor shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/overview).

Their page shows how to connect to it, and has example code and a library.

I don't really want to post a link-only answer, but the alternative would be to parrot the Adafruit page, which isn't really fair to them because this board wasn't even purchased from them.